Docker: Oracle Instant Client Dockerfile error
I have written a Docker Compose and a Dockerfile that provides me with a development environment. The container also runs without any problems up to the point where it is about the docker-php-ext-configure. Here I get the error message:
3.295 checking PHP version... 8.3.14, ok
3.299 checking OC18 Trace support... no
3.301 checking size of long... 8
3.355 checking if we're at 64-bit platform... yes
3.363 checking Oracle Instant Client directory... /usr/Lib/oracle/instantclient
3.363 checking Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... configure: error: Oracle Instant Client SDK header files not found
- - ====
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/Lib/oracle/instantclient
PS E: \src\10_tools\docker_development>
&& docker-php-ext-install oci8" did not complete successfully: exit code:

Do you have a solution?
Dockerfile
FROM php:8.3-apache

# Installiere notwendige Tools und PHP-Erweiterungen
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zip unzip git curl libpng-dev libonig-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev libaio1 \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd xml zip \
    && a2enmod rewrite

RUN mkdir -p /usr/lib/oracle \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_23_6 /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient \
    && echo '/usr/lib/oracle/instantclient' > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf \
    && ldconfig

RUN docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/instantclient \
    && docker-php-ext-install oci8

WORKDIR /var/www/html

I'm a Docker beginner and a bit at a loss.

Hi! Could you please post error text, not image? It is quite hustle to click on your link just to see some text. Stackoverflow recommendation "Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them." Obviously without clicking on that link that post doesn't make sense

This question is similar to: oracle instant client sdk header files not found linux. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Just a guess... Error message indicates it is looking in /usr/Lib/oracle/instantclient (capital L in Lib). Your script is using lower case. php:8.3-apache is going to be a Linux system and case sensitive.

The Instant Client install steps in Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python will give you some background and installation techniques that you may find useful to understand.

I checked your docker file and indeed you do not install Oracle Instant Client, you need to install it to make it work. Not sure what you do with second RUN command, but seems it is just basically doing nothing. You just create an empty directory and then symbolic link to nothing... But instead you must install Oracle Instant Client.
